# I will like to understand whether Case 1 or Case 2 will be applicable in this scenario

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given that set A contains 10 distinguishable objects and set B contains 6 distinguishable objects.

I will like to choose 2 objects from set A (with replacement): ${10 \choose 1}^2$

I will also like to choose 4 objects from set B (with replacement): ${6 \choose 1}^4$

Now, the next step is where I am confused. The next step will be to take these 2 objects selected from set A and 4 objects selected from set B and arrange them in a single line where their position matters.

My confusion stems from whether this step will be equivalent to:

- ***Case 1:*** 6!
- ***Case 2:*** ${6 \choose 2} * 2! * {4 \choose 4} * 4!$

where in Case 2, E.g. ${6 \choose 2}$ refers to choosing 2 positions out of the 6 positions in a line and then permuting them afterwards with 2!

Comment: You have the right concern. The number of ways to do the arrangements will depend on whether any duplicates were selected in the first step. You should count a few different scenarios separately (four of them, of which your cases are two).

Comment: both cases give the same value. Did you mean some other expression for case 2?

Comment: this happens because case 2 is just another way to count case 1

Comment: Ah yeah, I missed that the two given expressions are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description makes it sound as if at first order doesn’t matter and then you start arranging things on a line and then order matters. But your original counts of $10^2$ and $6^4$ were already counts of ordered tuples. Assuming that that was indeed what you wanted, it’s then not so complicated to combine these ordered tuples into an ordered arrangement. Just select $2$ spots in the ordered $6$-tuple for the $2$ objects from $A$ (thereby also selecting the other $4$ spots for the $4$ objects from $B$) and then fill the two ordered tuples into the combined ordered tuple in order. Thus, you have $10^2\cdot6^4\cdot\binom62$ different arrangements.

Comment: hang on, what exactly are you calculating? Are you calculating the total no. of ways, or only the ways of arranging?

Comment: @DS: The former (if I understand correctly what you mean by that).

Comment: (+1) Yes, then I agree with your answer. I had interpreted the OP's question as "Which one to use, Case 1 or Case 2"?

Comment: @DS: Yes, I think that was the question – my implicit answer was "neither".

Comment: See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment of Karl indicates, neither Case 1 nor Case 2 is appropriate here.  Although I could be mistaken, I strongly suspect that (as Karl's comment also indicates), in order to complete the problem, you have to **re-work** the first part of the problem.  That is, you have to consider the mutually exclusive cases of how many distinct objects were taken from A and from B.

The (very tedious) work is shown below.  I emphasize that I may well be overlooking a more elegant approach to the problem.

---

For selecting items from A :

- There are $~\displaystyle (10)~$ ways of selecting the same item twice.
  I will use the syntax [A:2] to represent this possibility.
- There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{2} = 45~$ ways of selecting two **distinct** items. 
  I will use the syntax [A:1-1] to represent this possibility.

**Note** 
$45 + 10 \neq 10^2 = 100,~$ and $~100~$ was reported by the OP (i.e. original poster).  The discrepancy is explained by noting that when two distinct items are selected, the order of selection is **irrelevant** to the second part of the problem.

---

For selecting items from B :

- There are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{1} = 6~$ ways of selecting the same item, four times.
  I will use the syntax [B:4] to represent this possibility.
- There are $~\displaystyle (6 \times 5) = 30~$ ways of selecting one item three times, and then a second item one time. 
  I will use the syntax [B:3-1] to represent this possibility.
- There are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} = 15~$ ways of selecting one item twice, and then selecting a separate item twice.
  I will use the syntax [B:2-2] to represent this possibility.
- There are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} \times 4 = 60~$ ways of selecting two distinct items, one time each, and then selecting a third item twice.
  I will use the syntax [B:2-1-1] to represent this possibility.
- There are $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{4} = 15~$ ways of selecting four distinct items.
  I will use the syntax [B:1-1-1-1] to represent this possibility.

---

In effect, the above case work has [partitioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) the two positive integers $~4~$ and $~2.$

Now, in order to complete the problem, unfortunately, the $~2 \times 5 = 10~$ cases have to handled separately.  To keep this answer as short as possible, I will leave the reader to review [Multinomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) on their own.

The basic idea is that if you have $~k~$ distinct items, and each item is selected $~a_i~$ times, where $~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,k\},~$ and if $~\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k a_i = n$:

then the number of distinct ways of arranging the items in a row is

$$\frac{n!}{(a_1)! \times (a_2)! \times \cdots \times (a_k)!} \tag1 $$

For ease of syntax, I will use the expression $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k}~$ to represent the expression in (1) above.

---

Then, the number of distinct distributions of the items in a row is given by summing each of the $~10~$ cases separately.  This summation is detailed below:

- [A:2] $~\times~$ [B:4]
  $~:~~~~\displaystyle [10 \times 6] \times \binom{6}{2,4} ~$ ways.
- [A:2] $~\times~$ [B:3-1]
  $~:~~~~\displaystyle [10 \times 30] \times \binom{6}{2,3,1} ~$ ways.
- [A:2] $~\times~$ [B:2-2]
  $~:~~~~\displaystyle [10 \times 15] \times \binom{6}{2,2,2} ~$ ways.
- [A:2] $~\times~$ [B:2-1-1]
  $~:~~~~\displaystyle [10 \times 60] \times \binom{6}{2,2,1,1} ~$ ways.
- [A:2] $~\times~$ [B:1-1-1-1]
  $~:~~~~\displaystyle [10 \times 15] \times \binom{6}{2,1,1,1,1} ~$ ways.

---

- [A:1-1] $~\times~$ [B:4]
  $~:~~~~\displaystyle [45 \times 6] \times \binom{6}{1,1,4} ~$ ways.
- [A:1-1] $~\times~$ [B:3-1]
  $~:~~~~\displaystyle [45 \times 30] \times \binom{6}{1,1,3,1} ~$ ways.
- [A:1-1] $~\times~$ [B:2-2]
  $~:~~~~\displaystyle [45 \times 15] \times \binom{6}{1,1,2,2} ~$ ways.
- [A:1-1] $~\times~$ [B:2-1-1]
  $~:~~~~\displaystyle [45 \times 60] \times \binom{6}{1,1,2,1,1} ~$ ways.
- [A:1-1] $~\times~$ [B:1-1-1-1]
  $~:~~~~\displaystyle [45 \times 15] \times \binom{6}{1,1,1,1,1,1} ~$ ways.

---

**Addendum**
After reviewing Joriki's more elegant answer, I sanity-checked the two results.  My final computation exactly agrees with his.

Since I don't believe in coincidences, I decided to stretch my intuition to understand $~\color{red}{why}~$ the computations agree.

For simplicity, consider the situation where two distinct items are selected from A and one item is selected four times from B.

My enumeration of this particular possibility is:

$$\binom{10}{2} \times \binom{6}{1} \times \binom{6}{1,1,4} = 45 \times 6 \times 30 = 8100.$$

Joriki's enumeration of this particular possibility is:

$$[10 \times 9] \times [6] \times \binom{6}{2} = 90 \times 6 \times 15 = 8100.$$

Comment: I disagree with the note you added at the top of your answer. I'm only counting each such configuration once. If I understand your answer correctly (I'm not sure I do), we're counting the same thing, just with wildly different efficiency :-) Our answers differ only slightly, not by a large factor as would have to be the case if your note was correct. I suspect that the small discrepancy is due to a small mistake in one of your calculations.

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the heads up.  I could well have misinterpreted your analysis.  I will edit my answer accordingly.  Also, I did double-check my Math, which I will now triple-check.  If you happen to spot an error in my Math, please advise.

Comment: Actually, the error was just in my addition of your numbers :-) They do add up to my result.